# Colon instead of "p." in Biblatex authoryear-comp

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm using the `authoryear-comp` style with `biblatex`. But when using citing commands, instead of `p/pp.` I would rather have a colon. I have tried these:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{: #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{: #1}
```

but get `, :` instead.

How can I remove the comma in citations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You also need to redefine `\postnotedelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite[99]{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]