# BibLaTeX in text reference Author (Year: Page)

Tags: biblatex

I need an in-text reference in LaTeX to display the result as Author (Year: Page)

**Desired result:**

> According to Scott & McFeaters (2011: 116), battlefield archaeology
> has evolved into a reliable field of study.

**My main page includes the following package reference**

```
\RequirePackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    url=false,
    giveninits=true
  ]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

**My code is:**

```
According to \autocite[116]{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011}, battlefield archaeology has evolved into a reliable field of study
```

**The article in my bib file is:**

```
@article{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011,
    title = {The Archaeology of Historic Battlefields: A History and Theoretical Development in Conflict Archaeology},
    volume = {19},
    doi = {10.1007/s10814-010-9044-8},
    pages = {103--132},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Archaeological Research},
    author = {Scott, Douglas and McFeaters, Andrew},
    date = {2011},
}
```

**However I am getting the result:**

> According to (Scott & McFeaters 2011: 116), battlefield archaeology
> has evolved into a reliable field of study

The above reference will be correct for the end-of-paragraph reference but I need the in-text reference to be Scott & McFeaters (2011: 116)

Comment: You can have both citation types, see my renewed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the format you like with `\textcite`.
Hence, you only need to set the `\autocite` to `\textcite` for inline citation with:

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcite}
```

You can have both citation types. You can get (Author, Year) with `\parencite`.

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011,
    title = {The Archaeology of Historic Battlefields: A History and Theoretical Development in Conflict Archaeology},
    volume = {19},
    doi = {10.1007/s10814-010-9044-8},
    pages = {103--132},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Archaeological Research},
    author = {Scott, Douglas and McFeaters, Andrew},
    date = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    url=false,
    giveninits=true
  ]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcite}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66395/101651:
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
With text cite: \textcite[116]{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011}

With auto cite:

According to \autocite[116]{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011}, battlefield archaeology has evolved into a reliable field of study

You can have both citation type \parencite[116]{scott_and_mcfeaters_2011}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]